# How to show that geodesic curvature of isoperimetric set is constant

Tags: riemannian-geometry, supremum-and-infimum, ricci-flow

A few months ago, I read Hamilton's **An isoperimetric estimate for the Ricci flow on the two-sphere**, which is collected in [Collected papers on Ricci flow](http://library.lol/main/29f472b9eea6a0145f9540d74409aeba).

For two-sphere, the isoperimetric ratio can be treated as
$$
C_s^2=\inf_{\Lambda} \frac{L^2}{4\pi}(\frac{1}{A_1}+\frac{1}{A_2})
\tag{1}
$$
the $L$ is the length of curve $\Lambda$, and $\Lambda$ dividing two-sphere to two parts with areas $A_1,A_2$.

Hamilton proved that the isoperimetric ratio can be attained by a curve $\overline\Lambda$. And he state that the geodesic curvature of $\overline\Lambda$ is constant
$$
k=\frac{L}{2}(\frac{1}{A_1}-\frac{1}{A_2})  \tag{2}
$$
by usual first variation. But he just state it without any detail or step. Recently, I read the variation of geodesic. So I want to prove (2), but I have no idea. And  I fail to find reference by using curvature, isoperimetric set as key words.

So, I want  a  framework for proving (2). I'd like to fill in the details myself as an exercise. Thanks.

**PS(2023-12-31):** Assuming $\overline\Lambda:[0,a]\rightarrow S^2$ is the curve of isoperimetric ratio.
$f(s,t):(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times[0,a]\rightarrow S^2$ is the variation of $\overline\Lambda$.  The variation field is
$$
V(t)=\partial_s f(0,t)  \tag{3}
$$
For fixed $s\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, we denote
$f_s(t) =f(s,t)$.  When $s=0$, $t$ is the arc length parameter of $f_s(t)$.  And, $N(s,t)$ is the normal vector of $f_s(t)$.  For  keeping the area of each part unchanged, we assume
$$
\int_0^a\int_0^s N(\tau,t)\cdot\partial_s f(\tau,t)d\tau dt=0
\tag{4}
$$
Differentiate (4), we have
$$
0=
\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^a\int_0^s 
N(\tau,t)\cdot\partial_s f(\tau,t)d\tau dt
=
\int_0^a N(s,t)\cdot\partial_s f(s,t) dt
\tag{4.1}
$$
Since when $s=0$, (4) always be right. Therefore, (4) is equal to
$$
\int_0^a N(s,t)\cdot\partial_s f(s,t) dt=0~~~~~~\forall s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)
\tag{4.2}
$$
The length of $f_s(t)$ is $L(s)=\int_0^a |\partial_t f(s,t)| dt$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
0=\frac{dL}{ds}|_{s=0} 
&=
\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0} \int_0^a |\partial_t f(s,t)| dt  \\
&=
\int_0^a \frac{
\langle 
\frac{D}{ds}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t},\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
\rangle
}{|\partial_t f(s,t)|} dt|_{s=0}   \\
&=
\int_0^a \frac{
\langle 
\frac{D}{dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s},\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
\rangle
}{|\partial_t f(s,t)|} dt|_{s=0}  
\tag{5}\\
\text{(when $s=0$, $|\partial_t f|=1$)} ~~~~~~~
&=
\int_0^a 
\frac{d}{dt}\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial s},
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\rangle 
-\langle 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial s},
\frac{D}{dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
\rangle 
dt|_{s=0}   
\\
\text{(when $s=0$, $\partial_s f=V(t)$, $f=\overline\Lambda (t)$)} ~~~~~~~
&= 
\langle V(t), \partial_t\overline\Lambda(t)\rangle |_0^a 
- \int_0^a \langle V(t),\frac{D}{dt}\frac{d\overline\Lambda}{dt}\rangle dt
\end{align}
$$
For any $t_1,t_2\in(0,a)$, let
$$
V(t)=N(t) \delta(t-t_1) -N(t)\delta(t-t_2)
\tag{6}
$$
where $\delta$ is Dirac delta function. Then, (5) imply that $k(\overline\Lambda(t_1))=k(\overline\Lambda(t_2))$.  By the arbitrariness of $t_1,t_2$ and parameterization of $\overline\Lambda$, we know that the geodesic curvatures of all points of $\overline\Lambda$ are equal. Then, Hamilton has show
$$
\int k ds = \frac{L^2}{2}(\frac{1}{A_1}-\frac{1}{A_2})
\tag{7}
$$
Therefore, $k=\frac{L}{2}(\frac{1}{A_1}-\frac{1}{A_2})$.

However, the above process is not complete, since we need to prove there is  variation satisfying (4) and its variation field is (6). I try to use exponential map to show the existence, but still have not finish.

Well, on the last day of 2023, I wish all who see here happy.

Comment: The mentionned site cannot be reached.

Comment: @JeanMarie  I can reach it. Maybe you need a VPN ( https://lantern.io/ ).  Or  search "Collected papers on Ricci flow"  in Library Genesis, you can find it too.

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers. Compute first variation of $L+\lambda A$. Or $L^2/A$.

Comment: @Deane  Thanks, but there seemly is not constraint.  And is it $A=A_1+A_2$?  I think I should  consider analogue of the one-parameter family of parallel curves $\Lambda_r$ at distance $r$ from $\overline\Lambda$ (as 242th page of Hamilton's paper). For example, for any $p\in \overline\Lambda$, $\Lambda_r(p)$ is the curve which is get by   only the point near $p$ is moved.  But I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: You can use $A=A_1$ or $A=A_2$. You cannot restrict to parallel curves only. You have to allow any smooth variation. The point is that any variation has to leave the area of each part unchanged.

Comment: @Deane  According your help, I give a uncomplete proof which is added above.  But I still not using  Lagrange multiplier.  Let me  think about it tomorrow or the next day first. Thanks.

Comment: You don’t need to use the Dirac delta function. You just need the fact that if $$\int V(t)f(t)\,dt =0 $$ for any smooth $V$, then $f=0$.

Comment: @Deane  I know the fact you said. But I can't get the constant geodesic curvature from it. Could you talk it detail?

Comment: You want to reduce everything to formulas restricted to $\tau = 0$. You can differentiate (4) with respect to $\tau$ and then set $\tau = 0$. I also don't see how you got (5). Perhaps you could provide a detailed calculation?

Comment: @Deane  Thanks for your patience. I added the calculation of (5). Besides, differentiating (4) respect to $\tau$ seemly will be complex, I guess you should mean respect to $s$.  I do it to get an equivalent condition of (4), namely (4.2). But that still doesn't circumvent existence of special variation.