# How to calculate the area in variation?

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, area, calculus-of-variations

$(M^2,g)$ is Riemannian surface. $\lambda(t):[0,L]\rightarrow M^2$ is a simple closed curve.
The variation of $\lambda (t)$ is
$$
f(s,t):(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times[0,L] \rightarrow M^2
$$
such that $f(0,t)=\lambda(t), f(s,0)=f(s,L)$. For fix $s\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, $N(s,t)$ is the normal vector of $f(s,t)$. Then, I guess that the directed area closed by $f(0,t)$ and f(s,t) is
$$
A(s)=\int_0^L\int_0^s N(\tau,t)\cdot f_s(\tau,t) d\tau dt 
\tag{1}
$$
where $f_s(\tau,t)=\partial_s f(\tau,t)$.

Of course, the above statement is not rigorous, in order to guarantee the existence of normal vectors we need $f(s,t)$ to be regular enough. Besides, $\epsilon$ may needs to be sufficiently small. But I don't think that's the core. So I didn't really think about the rigor.

I guess the (1) in  [another problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834833/how-to-show-that-geodesic-curvature-of-isoperimetric-set-is-constant). Seemly, I'm not the only one who  think it's right. But now, when I try to show it is right, I don't know how to start...

> I've drawn a picture of the problem, just to make it a little bit more intuitive
> [image]

Comment: To my limited understanding, $f$ looks like a parametric surface, for which the area is kind of [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_surface#Surface_area), provided $f$ is smooth, no matter if it's the variation of some curve or not.

Comment: @Al.G. It is parametric surface, Thanks. Let me think how to prove it.